# Unable to create RBAC using GoogleProvider

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth, rbac, trpc

I am creating an app in NextJs and I am using NextAuth. I want to use GoogleProvider.
I want to have two roles in my application, suppose these are 'A' and 'B". When a user signs up, he/she will be able to select the role when signing up.
I have searched a lot but could not find anything about this.

Flow I tried --

- The user lands on the signup page
- Enters email and role
- A user is added in data with the same creds
- Login with Google Flow is triggered
- But when the user signs in using the same email he registers earlier.
- NextAuth throws an error something like - `Please use the account you used previously.`

Here are my NextAuthOptions

```js
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    newUser: '/register',
  },
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: user.id,
      },
    }),
    signIn: async ({ user, profile }) => {
      console.log(profile)

      if (!user) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid user provided by google.'))
      }

      const existingUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({ where: { email: user.email } })
      if (!existingUser) {
        return false
      }

      return true
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: 'consent',
          access_type: 'offline',
          response_type: 'code',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how can I achieve this? Or if there is any application already created for this would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

NextAuth, and the Google Provider, is mostly about [authentication](https://www.permit.io/blog/authn-vs-authz), while your use case is more about authorization.

To achieve this user role selection and the further task of validating permissions, you need to either:

- Save the roles in your database
- Use an [authorization library/product](https://www.permit.io/blog/how-to-add-rbac-in-nextjs) that can help you with managing roles and permissions.

Comment: My concern is, how will I signup a user with specific role if I am using GoogleProvider.

Comment: You can use NextAuth callbacks to call the API you wish to assign role with https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks